# Safe accelerometer data in database

Tags: java, database

I am trying to safe a value derived from the accelerometer data in to a database, using nodeJs and phpMyAdmin. till now it did not work but don't know what to do.

this is my main activity

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: X: " + sensorEvent.values[0] + "Y: " + sensorEvent.values[1] + "Z: " + sensorEvent.values[2]);

    xValue.setText("xValue: " + sensorEvent.values[0]);
    yValue.setText("yValue: " + sensorEvent.values[1]);
    zValue.setText("zValue: " + sensorEvent.values[2]);

    double rf = Math.sqrt((sensorEvent.values[0]*sensorEvent.values[0]) + (sensorEvent.values[1]*sensorEvent.values[1]) + (sensorEvent.values[2]*sensorEvent.values[2]));

    ravefactor.setText("ravefactor: "+ rf);

    if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastUpdate > 30000) {
        sendRavemeter(rf);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}

private void sendRavemeter(double rf) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    try {
        double lat = 8;
        double lon = 9;
        request.execute("/ravemeter/factor/" + rf + "/" + lat + "/" + lon, "POST").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is what I have in my index.js

```
// Import and instantiate MySQL connector
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "iosense.tudelft.nl",
  port: "3306",
  user: "user95",
  password: "123yWWjw",
  database: "database95",
  connectionLimit: 100,
  multipleStatements: true,
  debug: false
});

// Import web server library Express
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
// Define the web application with Express
const app = express();
// Add the ability to parse the request body (instead of the raw string)
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));


app.post('/ravemeter', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;
// Check the body contains the player name
  if (body.lat !== undefined && body.lon !== undefined && body.ravefactor !== undefined) {

    //var computationResult = calculateSth(body.lat, body.lon, body.ravefactor);

    // The ? will be replace by all the parameters of player

    const sql = 'INSERT INTO `TableRaveApp` SET ?';
    // Create a player object with all parameters
    const ravemeterData = {
        lat: body.lat,
        lon: body.lon,
        ravefactor: body.ravefactor
    };
    // Send the query and the data (player) to be executed
    execSQL(sql, ravemeterData).then( (result) => {
      response.send("ravemeter activated");
    }).catch( (error) => {
      response.send(error);
    });
  } else {
    response.send({error: "Missing gps and/or ravefactor."});
  }
});

app.post('/ravemeter/factor/:ravefactor/:lat/:lon', (request, response) => {
        const ravefactor = request.query.ravefactor;
        const sql = 'INSERT INTO `TableRaveApp` SET ?';
        // Create a player object with all parameters
        const ravemeterData = {
            lat: request.query.lat,
            lon: request.query.lon,
            ravefactor: request.query.ravefactor
        };
        // Send the query and the data (player) to be executed
        execSQL(sql, ravemeterData).then( (result) => {
          response.send("ravemeter activated");
        }).catch( (error) => {
          response.send(error);
        });
});

app.get('/ravemeter/factor/:ravefactor', (request, response) => {
    const rave = request.query.ravefactor;
    const sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS \'num_persons\', AVG(`ravefactor`) AS         \'avg_ravefactor\' FROM `TableRaveApp`' ;
// Send the query (without data) to be executed
execSQL(sql, rave).then( (result) => {
    response.send({ravefactor_values: result});
}).catch( (error) => {
    response.send(error);
});
});

app.get('/ravemeter/area/:area', (request, response) => {
    const area = request.query.area;
    const LatLonArea = getLatLonArea(area);
    const sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS \'num_persons\', AVG(`ravefactor`) AS     \'avg_ravefactor\' FROM `TableRaveApp` WHERE lat BETWEEN ? AND ? AND lon BETWEEN ? AND ? ';
// Send the query (without data) to be executed
execSQL(sql, latLonArea).then( (result) => {
    response.send({ravemeter_values: result});
}).catch( (error) => {
    response.send(error);
});
});

function getLatLonArea(areaName) {
    switch(areaName) {
        case 'mainStage': return [6568,56675,7634,3948];
        case 'bravoStage': return [6568,56675,7634,3948];
        case 'technoStage': return [3245, 5469, 8795, 5430];
    case 'foodArea': return [4239, 5438, 5432, 2349];
    }
}

/**
 * Execute an SQL query.
**/
function execSQL(sql, data) {
    // Build a promise (result via then(), error via catch())
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            if (error) {
                // Write a log to keep track of errors
                console.error(error);
                // Reject the promise, reject will trigger the catch()
                reject(error);
            }
            const query = connection.query(sql, data, (error, result) => {
                connection.release();
                if (error) {
                    if (error.errno == 1062) { // MySQL error for duplicated     entries
                        reject({error: "Already exist.", errno: 500});
                    } else {
                        // Write a log to keep track of errors
                        console.error(error);
                        // Reject the promise, reject will trigger the catch()
                        reject({error: 'Something wrong happened :(', errno: 500});
                    }
                }
                // Result from the database, resolve will trigger then()
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
}

// Start the web server
app.listen(8081, 'localhost');
console.info('Running on http://localhost:8081');
```

I don't know how to fix it because it does not give any error so can't google it. I also made a http request.
somebody know what to do??

thank you!!
[This is a screenshot of what I actually want to do, but now I do it manually with an extension. I want to post it to the database from the Mainactivity with the request.execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42X6u.png)

Comment: If there's no error, what does it do? What have you tried doing to debug it? Are there any side effects you can use to figure out where it might be failing?

Comment: Please be more specific about what happens when you run it.

Comment: I have updated a picture with a description what I wanted to achieve